# showing product variations in tabs instead of dropdown

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display product variations in tabs instead of drop down on products page.I have struggled a lot but could not found any solution.Please help if anyone knows how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart() {
        global $product, $post;
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
        ?>
        <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>"method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="<?php echo $value['variation_id']?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
            <?php
            if(!empty($value['attributes'])){
                foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {
                ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $attr_key?>" value="<?php echo $attr_value?>">
                <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b><?php echo implode('/', $value['attributes']);?></b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $value['price_html'];?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo apply_filters('single_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ), $product->product_type); ?></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php
        }}
```

//You were missing a closing bracket. Thank you!